# Additional axis on 3D surface in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Suppose I plot a 3d graph using

```
[X,Y,Z] = peaks(25);
figure
surf(X,Y,Z);
```

How can I add addtional x and y axis with labels to the z=0 plane like the red ones shown in this picture? I would like to keep the original axis as is.
[image]

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you want two axes in the figure, or just to replace the one you have with the red one?

Comment: I want to keep the original axis (edited my post).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just draw my own fake axis. I'm not sure there is a better solution, but this one works.

```
[X,Y,Z] = peaks(25);
figure
surf(X,Y,Z);

hold on;

%define the plot limits
xlim_arr = [-4 4];
ylim_arr = [-5 5];
zlim_arr = [-10 10];

%fix the limits of the real axes
xlim(xlim_arr);
ylim(ylim_arr);
zlim(zlim_arr);

%add grid and labels through all x-points
for i=xlim_arr(1):xlim_arr(2)
    plot3([i i],[ylim_arr(1) ylim_arr(2)], [0 0], 'Color', [0.7 0.7 0.7], 'LineWidth',0.4);

    text(i, ylim_arr(1)-0.4, 0, num2str(i));
    text(i, ylim_arr(2)+0.4, 0, num2str(i));
end

%add grid and labels through all y-points
for i=ylim_arr(1):ylim_arr(2)
    plot3([xlim_arr(1) xlim_arr(2)], [i i], [0 0], 'Color', [0.7 0.7 0.7], 'LineWidth',0.4);

    text(xlim_arr(1)-0.4, i, 0, num2str(i));
    text(xlim_arr(2)+0.4, i, 0, num2str(i));
end

%add the bold frame to highlight the fake axes
px = [xlim_arr(1) xlim_arr(1) xlim_arr(2) xlim_arr(2) xlim_arr(1)];
py = [ylim_arr(1) ylim_arr(2) ylim_arr(2) ylim_arr(1) ylim_arr(1)];
pz = [0 0 0 0 0];

plot3(px,py,pz, 'k', 'LineWidth', 0.5);
```

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks. I would have prefered a matlab command, but this way works too. Thanks!